# Recursive command parser that solves a repeat statement

Tags: java, parsing, syntax

I am building a parser that recognizes simple commands such as "DOWN.", "UP." and "REP 3.". It must be able to parse the commands rather freely. It should be legal to write

```
"DOWN % asdf asdf asdf
."
```

Where % represents a comment and the fullstop signifying *end-of-command*. This fullstop can be on the next line.

This is all good and well so far, however I'm struggling with the Rep part (represents Repeat.)
I should be able to issue a command as follows:

```
DOWN .DOWN. REP 3 " DOWN. DOWN. 
  DOWN   . % hello this is a comment
  REP 2 " DOWN. ""
```

This should give me ***17 DOWNS***. The semantics is as follows for repeat: REP x " commands " where x is the amount of times it shall repeat the commands listed inside the quotation marks. Note that REP can be nested inside of REP. The following code is for handling the DOWN command. The incoming text is read from *System.in* or a *text file*.

```
    public void repeat(String workingString) {

    if (workingString.matches(tokens)) {
        if (workingString.matches("REP")) {
            repada();
        } else
        if (workingString.matches("(DOWN).*")) {
            String job = workingString.substring(4);
            job = job.trim();
            if (job.equals("")) {
                String temp= sc.next();
                temp= temp.trim();

                // Word after DOWN.
                if (temp.matches("\\.")) {
                    leo.down()
                    // If word after DOWN is a comment %
                } else if (temp.matches("%.*")) {
                    boolean t = comment();
                } else {
                    throw SyntaxError();
                }
            } else if (job.matches("\\..*")) {
                workingString += job;
                System.out.println("Confirm DOWN with .");
            }

        } else if (workingString.matches("\\.")) {
            instructions += workingString;
            System.out.println("Fullstop");
        } else if (workingString.matches("%.*")) {
            comment();
        } else {
            // work = sc.next();
            work = work.trim().toUpperCase();
            System.out.println(work);
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("No such token: " + workingString);
    }
}
```

I got a working start on the repeat function:

```
public String repada(){
        String times = sc.next();
        times.trim();
        if (times.matches("%.*")) {
            comment();
            times = sc.next();
        }
        String quote = sc.next();
        quote.trim();
        if(quote.matches("%.*")){
            comment();
            quote = sc.next();
        }
        String repeater = "";
        System.out.println("REP " + times + " "+quote);}
```

However I'm thinking my whole system of doing things might need a rework. Any advice on how I could more easily solve this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would think that you should have a "process command" function that works kind of how you have it, but the rep x command should create a loop that recursively calls the process command function x number of times for the command string. This way, you can have as many Reps inside of Reps that you need, as it seems like that is the command that is giving you trouble.

Comment: I would also simply split by the fullstop. `.` Process command will handle a command between the fullstop - seeing `Rep x` will then split using your quote formatting and use what is in the quotes and recursively feed it back into the process command function x times.

Comment: It's not clear to me why you use `.` tokens. Your simple commands are just single words, and your `REP` command doesn't seem to use  `.` terminators (at least, from your examples.)